# How to Set Java Home for Notebook in SageMaker

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, java-8, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

So it seems that I have Java installed after running the below line in the SageMaker Notebook Terminal:

```
bash-4.2$ sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

In the terminal I write the following to confirm:

```
bash-4.2$ java -version 
java version "1.7.0_261" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.6.22.1.83.amzn1-x86_64 u261-b02) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.261-b02, mixed mode)
```

In my notebook I have the following Lines of code:

```
import tabula

tabula.environment_info()
```

The notebook results in an error with:

```
java -version` faild. `java` command is not found from this Pythonprocess. Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for `java`
```

Yet, in the terminal I see this:

```
bash-4.2$ java -version 
java version "1.7.0_261" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.6.22.1.83.amzn1-x86_64 u261-b02) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.261-b02, mixed mode)
```

I definitely have a java environment. How can I set my notebook to find this?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to install it from sagemaker notebook via !sudo yum install ...
You can verify the path in the notebook to confirm the linking